# Jetty, isSecure() returning false on HTTPS connection

Tags: java, https, jetty, embedded-jetty

I have hit a problem with `isSecure()` returning false on request arriving on HTTPS connection, actually a HTTPS connection with valid certificates from common CA, both user and server certificates. Why?

Here is a callstack:

[image: callstack]

But the member that is returned by `isSecure()` is false:

[image]

This is with Jetty 9.4.8.

**UPDATE**

On `HttpChannelOverHttp(HttpChannel).onRequest(MetaData$Request) line: 638` I see `_request.setSecure(HttpScheme.HTTPS.is(request.getURI().getScheme()));` which could set up the flag to true. Unfortunately, the URI is incomplete of `//host.name:8081/path/a/b/c` format and `getScheme()` returns `null` which results in `false` being returned by `is()`. WTH?

**UPDATE 2**

It appears that I can fix this by adding the following to `HttpConfiguration` in `jetty-config.xml`:

```xml
                <Call name="addCustomizer">
                  <Arg>
                      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer" />
                  </Arg>
                </Call>
```

But it is unclear to my why is this necessary and why it does not work OOTB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered yourself, you were missing a configuration.

The fact that you felt you needed to manually add this configuration tells me you are using an old version of Jetty. (please consider upgrading, it is easier to control this now, as evidenced below)

The `SecureRequestCustomizer` in the `HttpConfiguration` is responsible for handling the identification of SSL Certificates, SNI, Host checks, the various `HttpServletRequest` attributes for SSL/TLS, etc..

It looks like this on older versions of Jetty.

```xml
<Call name="addCustomizer">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer" />
  </Arg>
</Call>
```

On Newer versions of Jetty this is added by the [`jetty-ssl.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-ssl.xml) xml (part of the [`ssl`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server/src/main/config/modules/ssl.mod) module), and it looks like this ...

```xml
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- [snip] ssl connector setup -->

  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <!-- Create a TLS specific HttpConfiguration based on the        -->
  <!-- common HttpConfiguration defined in jetty.xml               -->
  <!-- Add a SecureRequestCustomizer to extract certificate and    -->
  <!-- session information                                         -->
  <!-- =========================================================== -->
  <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer">
          <Arg name="sniHostCheck" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.sniHostCheck" default="true"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="stsMaxAgeSeconds" type="int"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsMaxAgeSeconds" default="-1"/></Arg>
          <Arg name="stsIncludeSubdomains" type="boolean"><Property name="jetty.ssl.stsIncludeSubdomains" default="false"/></Arg>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>

</Configure>
```

The reason this isn't on by default is that a request can be considered secure without Jetty handling the actual SSL/TLS.  This is the forwarded scenario, from a load balancer, proxy, firewall, gateway, etc...   In that scenario, the SSL/TLS is handled by another process, which talks to Jetty via a non-secure channel (standard HTTP without encryption, proxy, unix sockets, etc).  The fact that the connection is secure or not is then communicated to jetty via "forwarded" headers.

This forwarded behavior is controlled by a different customizer `org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer` (found in [`jetty-http-forwarded.xml`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server/src/main/config/etc/jetty-http-forwarded.xml), which part of the [`http-forwarded`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/jetty-server/src/main/config/modules/http-forwarded.mod) module)

Comment: As I have stated in the OP, I use Jetty 9.4.8.

Comment: Then, as you seem to be using Jetty 9.4.8 and the distribution, you should know that [editing the content in `${jetty.home}` (aka the distribution) is not recommended](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.8.v20171121/startup-base-and-home.html).  Setup a proper `${jetty.base}` and use the modules.

Comment: We use embedded Jetty, so we either instantiate the `Server` through code or through `jetty-config.xml`.

Comment: Cool.  Added the appropriate [tag:embedded-jetty] tag to your question then. :-)